# How to list currently installed MS Office apps programmatically?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office, office365, installer

I want to understand the contents of my Office edition, i.e. which apps (Word, Excel, Outlook) are installed on my machine. For example, I can see this info when I do repair of my Office package, where the icons symbolize apps

[image]

but I don't see this info in the **Apps** in system settings, where only one single MS Office app is listed, but not separate apps, so I do not know what is installed.

[image]

I put tag [powershell] but I'm open to any programmatic solutions including CMD.

Comment: Might check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099646/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-microsoft-office-from-its-build-number-in-power.... But reg paths `"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"` and/or `"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"` are usually helpful for programmatically too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you run the ROIScan script: https://gist.github.com/joerodgers/b1c6ec34801917d4ec4a700491f8ace3.

The result will show all Office apps and other information like following image:

[image]

Comment: awesome, works like a charm